# ng-Animate-ref not working

Tags: angularjs, css, css-transforms, ng-animate

I have been trying to animate the list items moving to cart. I saw a [video](https://vimeo.com/139345348) where it was mentioned that the code structure for both the list items need to be same, so I restructured my code as well. I also read the angular documentation, but somehow I am not able to find the css I wrote for animation when I inspect the code, although I am able to see correct `ng-animate-ref` id when I inspect,  but the animation does not happen.

```
<div ng-controller="menuCtrl">
    <div flex="60" >
         <ul class="product-list ">
             <li  class="item"  ng-repeat="product in products track by product.ID">
                 <a href="" ng-animate-ref="{{ product.ID }}"  ng-click= "addToCart(product)">
                     <i class="fa fa-cart-plus" style="color: black;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                 </a>
                 <a href=""  ng-click="fnA(product)">{{product.Name}}</a>
                 <a href=""  ng-click="fnB(product)"><i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true" ></i></a>
                    <button ng-click="fnC(product);">Get Addon</button>
             </li>
         </ul>
    </div>

    <div flex="40" ng-if="cart.length" >
         <ul class="product-list ">
            <li  class="item "  ng-repeat="product in cart track by product.ID"  >
               <a href=""  ng-click="fnA(product)" ng-animate-ref="{{ product.ID }}">{{product.Name}}</a>
               <a href="" ng-click="fnB(product)">
                   <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"  style="text-align: right; color: red; font-size: 12px;vertical-align: middle "></i>
               </a>
             </li>
         </ul>
    </div>

css:

ul li.ng-leave{
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 25000ms ease ;
    -moz-transition: opacity 25000ms ease ;
    -ms-transition: opacity 25000ms ease ;
    -o-transition: opacity 25000ms ease ;
    transition: opacity 25000ms ease ;
}

ul li.ng-leave-active{
    opacity:0;
}

a.ng-anchor{
    z-index: 10;
}

a.ng-anchor-in{
    -webkit-transition: all 25000ms ease ;
    -moz-transition: all 25000ms ease ;
    -ms-transition: all 25000ms ease ;
    -o-transition: all 25000ms ease ;
    transition: all 25000ms ease ;
}

I put high values for transition so I could see what was happening. 
I don't see where I went wrong.
```

Comment: Made code more readable (especially in the fixed width textarea). However, a plunker (https://plnkr.co/) would be useful to test provided code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'leave' state animation, try with 'enter' animation. See if the following works :

```
ul li.ng-enter {
  opacity:0;

  -webkit-transition: opacity 25000ms ease ;
  -moz-transition: opacity 25000ms ease ;
  -ms-transition: opacity 25000ms ease ;
  -o-transition: opacity 25000ms ease ;
  transition: opacity 25000ms ease ;
}

ul li.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 25000ms ease ;
  -moz-transition: opacity 25000ms ease ;
  -ms-transition: opacity 25000ms ease ;
  -o-transition: opacity 25000ms ease ;
  transition: opacity 25000ms ease ;
}
```

Also make sure ngAnimate dependency has been added to your app.